# Program Not Entering Second Loop for the second time

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am creating my own bash script, but when I get out the second menu, the code don't let me enter into the second menu again.

The only way I had to explain this bug is that when I put 6 to go back to the first while the read fixes the 6 what causes confusion with the problem?
But that does not make sense because if it fixed the 6 would do echo " <--- back"

Can someone tell me why?

```
  while [ "$myscript" != "6" ]
   do
    echo "Script Menu"
    echo " 1 - Open"
    echo " 2 - Download"            
    echo " 3 - Update && Upgrade"   
    echo " 6 - Exit"

    echo "Choose  Your Script: "
    read myscript

    case $myscript in
            1)
                while [ "$open" != "6" ]
                    do
                        clear
                        echo "Open Menu"
                        echo " 1 - Rythombox"
                        echo " 2 - Anaconda"
                        echo " 3 - VSCode"
                        echo " 4 - Terminal"
                        echo " 6 - <-----Back"

                        echo "Choose Your Open: "
                        read open 

                        case $open in
                            1) 
                                echo "  Opening Rhythmbox"
                                gnome-terminal --tab -- "rhythmbox"
                            ;;
                            6) 
                                echo "<--- Back"
                            ;;

                            *)
                               echo "Not a option!"
                            ;;

                        esac
          done
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It's hard to tell from the incomplete code fragment, but is the problem that `$open` is still "6" from the last time? If not, please edit your script down to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem, so people can see/try it out for themselves without having to wade through the unrelated parts of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as Gordon Davisson noticed, is indeed *that `$open` is still "6" from the last time*.
The solution is simply to bring reading and comparing the input choice in a sane order, not testing `[ "$open" != "6" ]` before the variable  has been read in:

```
while   echo "Script Menu"
        echo " 1 - Open"
        echo " 2 - Download"            
        echo " 3 - Update && Upgrade"   
        echo " 6 - Exit"
        echo "Choose  Your Script: "
        read myscript
        [ "$myscript" != "6" ]
do
    case $myscript in
    1)  while   clear
                echo "Open Menu"
                echo " 1 - Rythombox"
                echo " 2 - Anaconda"
                echo " 3 - VSCode"
                echo " 4 - Terminal"
                echo " 6 - <-----Back"
                echo "Choose Your Open: "
                read open 
                [ "$open" != "6" ]
        do
            case $open in
            1)  echo "  Opening Rhythmbox"
                gnome-terminal --tab -- "rhythmbox"
                ;;
            6)  echo "<--- Back"
                ;;
            *)  echo "Not a option!"
                ;;
            esac
        done
    esac
done
```